# Get Count of an Item of Generic List

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, generic-list

I have a generic list of int `List<int>()` and I want to know Count of a item of it. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What special items are in your `List<int>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

using the extension method is the simplest way

```
int count = list.Count(i => i > 10);// get the count of those which is bigger than 10
```

Comment: It worked. but I wanted this:list.Count(i => i == 10);Thank u very much

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee So what you need is `int count = myList.Count(i => i.Equals(10));`
`

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee - `Count` relies on `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get a count for the number of items in the list you can use an expression to do this:

```
int count = myList.Count(i => i.Equals(5));
```

Comment: `Equals` is a method on int - it needs to be an upper case E.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869

```
public void Linq73() 
{ 
    int[] factorsOf300 = { 2, 2, 3, 5, 5 }; 

    int uniqueFactors = factorsOf300.Distinct().Count(); 

    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} unique factors of 300.", uniqueFactors); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count of A Generic List (generated from stored procedure)

```
List<GetDivisionsForGroup> GroupDivision = new List<GetDivisionsForGroup>();
        String storedProcedures = "Sp_GetDivisionsForGroup " + grpid;
        GroupDivision = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<GetDivisionsForGroup>("exec " + storedProcedures).ToList();

        if (GroupDivision.Count > 0)
        {

        }
```